# Control the number of error application in Event Viewer with Python

Tags: python, event-viewer

With Python I need to find the total number of application errors in the event log.
[image: application error]

With this code I find the number of all application Event Viewer logs.

```
import win32evtlog
import win32event
import win32api

server = 'localhost' # name of the target computer to get event logs
logtype = 'Application'
hand = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(server, logtype)
flags = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_FORWARDS_READ | win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
total = win32evtlog.GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(hand)
print(total)
```

How can it be filtered?